# Ionic Push User identification issue

Tags: javascript, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ionic-framework

I'm having this issue where I register for Push using `$ionicPush.register()` But I'm not doing user identification at any point using `$ionicUser`(like the docs suggest). So, I'm only calling `$ionicPush.register()` and I wait for that promise to resolve and I'm storing the device_token on my server, eg.

```
$ionicPush.register({
  onNotification: function(notification) {
    //....
  }
}).then(function(deviceToken) {
  //Save device-token to my server
  UserService.saveIosDeviceToken(user.id, deviceToken) 
    .then(function(user) {
      return user;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I have noticed that regardless of calling `$ionicUser.identify(...)` or not, an `$ionicUser` will be created (which you can see in the Dashboard). Now the issue that I'm having is that **I'm not always getting a device token**. ie. I end up with some(not all) Ionic Users with no device tokens (therefore no device token I can store on my server), eg.

[image]

Do you guys know what's going on? I'm reading the [FAQ here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-faq#section-no-valid-device-tokens) and it says: > *"If you are using $ionicPush.register() without passing a user object, you should make sure you are waiting for the $ionicPush.identify() promise to complete."* -- Could this be the likely cause? and **How do I pass a user** to `$ionicPush.register()`?

Let me know what you guys think, I really need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Regards,

-J

Comment: well it is in alpha...so expect to have tons of problems with no solutions. you may be doing everything right. I had my ionic user saying everything was great and working but never got any users to show up. I would just wait for some updates and see if it clears itself up.

Comment: Check the following link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933909/ionic-push-not-working-user-not-registered/34403098#34403098

Comment: Thanks man, I'm happy to see the community is so kind and helpful.