# New Ionic push (2016) not registering users in ionic dashboard

Tags: ionic-framework, push, registration

I have spent the last week reading through stacks of suggestions about how to get things working on (the new) Ionic Push, but it seems not to be working and I'm about to give up. I have the following code in my app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'ionic.service.push'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }

    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
/*  ******************************* */



  // enable push notifications
  Ionic.io();

  var user = Ionic.User.current();

  if (!user.id) {
    user.id = Ionic.User.anonymousId();

    user.save();
  }

  var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true,
    "onNotification": function(notification) {
      var payload = notification.payload;
      console.log(notification, payload);
    },
    "onRegister": function(data) {
      console.log(data.token);
    },
    "pluginConfig": {
      "ios": {
        "badge": true,
        "sound": true
       },
       "android": {
         "iconColor": "#343434"
       }
    }
  });

  push.register(function(token) {
    console.log("Device token:", token.token);
    push.addTokenToUser(user);
    user.save();
  });

  Ionic.User.current(user);

  });
})
```

It appears to me something is missing. I have read the suggestions to the [Ionic push not working - user not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933909/ionic-push-not-working-user-not-registered) but it still doesn't seem to register the user at the dashboard/server end (or whatever it's called).

Anyone with ideas?

Initially when setting up the project I run the following:

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client

ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="MY GCM_PROJECT_NUMBER"

ionic config set dev_push false

ionic push --google-api-key <my api key>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution ?